# Converting array object to pairs object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like the one below.

```js
var data = {data1:"test",data2:"test2"}
```

How can I convert this to the following object?

```js
[{data1:"test"},{data2:"test2"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.entries()` with `array#map` to generate an array of objects from your object.

```js
const data = { data1:"test", data2:"test2" },
      result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects are dictionaries, you can use `Object.keys` to put object property names into an array and then map each array item to a new object like this:

```
var result = Object.keys(data).map(k => ({ [k]: data[k] }));
```

Comment: Add an explanation, please.

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` returns keys in object as `[data1, data2 ]`. map iterate over the array and also return an array. here `k` is a key from `[data1, data2 ]`. then in map, he prepared a `{ [k]: data[k] }` that is appending in the array will be return by map.

Comment: `for...in` also works, but yeah I would definitely recommend using more "native" ways to iterate over objects.

Answer (score 0):

Old school way:

```js
const data = {data1:"test",data2:"test2"};
let result = [];
for(let key in data){
  result.push({[key]: data[key]});
}
console.log(result);
```

New way (use `Object.Keys`, like mentioned in another answer. It's different on purpose to encourage uniqueness. For more "compact" and "resource-efficient" code use the other answer mentioned by Alex Pereverzyev):

```js
const data = { data1:"test", data2:"test2" }
const result = [];
//This returns the keys of data ("data1", "data2"). Then use bracket notation to find the value in the object (data["data1"]):
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  //Push into the array the name of the key along with its value
  result.push({[key]: data[key]})
});
console.log(result);
```

Please note that there are many ways to do this, the ones I mentioned are just a few.